# Redux offline createOffline vs Offline API?

Tags: redux-offline

What is the difference between createOffline and offline api?

The redux offline home page shows an example using offline
https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline

In the docs there are examples to both
https://github.com/redux-offline/redux-offline/tree/develop/docs/api

What is the difference, which is used when and why?

Thanks!